# I'm doing something wrong -- Nested Types

Tags: swift

Alright so I'm practicing nested types, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here, it's probably something really simple, but it's just not coming to me right now, so I thought I'd ask for help. I keep getting **<< error type >>** when creating an intance of my *Employee* class. Any tips?

```
class Employee {
  var name: String
  var profession: Profession

  enum Profession {
    var salary = 0

    case .Developer, .Engineer, .QA, .ProjectLead

    func averageSalary() {
      switch self {
        case .Developer:
          salary = 85_000
        case .Engineer:
          salary = 90_000
        case .QA:
          salary = 70_000
        case .ProjectLead:
          salary = 90_000
      }
      println("Average Salary: \(salary)")
    }
  }

  init(name: String, profession: Profession) {
    self.name = name
    self.profession = profession
  }
}

let c = Employee(name: "Justin", profession: Employee.Profession.Developer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with your `Profession` enum.

First off, enums cannot have stored properties, like `salary`. You can use associated values if that suits your needs. See: [Swift Language Reference: Enumerations - Associated Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID148)

Otherwise, for your `averageSalary` func, I would just return the new average salary as an `Int`

Secondly, you should not be including the dot at the beginning of each case declaration. So:

`case Developer, Engineer, QA, ProjectLead`

Comment: You don't have to use a dot before the enum cases in a switch statement due to its direct reference. It is optional.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the enum:

> Enums may not contain stored properties

(the salary variable)

and you should not write a dot before the case names:

```
enum Profession {

    case Developer, Engineer, QA, ProjectLead

    func averageSalary() -> Int {
        switch self {
        case Developer:
            return 85_000
        case Engineer:
            return 90_000
        case QA:
            return 70_000
        case ProjectLead:
            return 90_000
        }
    }
}
```